# Calculate Number of Working Days based on a Month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Using Power Bi desktop,
I need to create a query where the result will be the current month's working days.
For example July 2021 has 22 working days and so on.

My goal for achieving this will be to be to average the number of lines processed divided into the number of working days for the current month.

Will this be possible?

Comment: Weekends are only Saturday and Sunday? or there are other off days. If yes, do you have any calendar table for that?

Comment: Just Saturdays and Sundays, I dont mind keeping holidays.

Comment: then you can create a measure like sum of days where day not equal Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with the query?

Comment: check my answer help or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always get the job done only by creating just a single measure and nothing else like following

```
    _count = 
    COUNTX (
        FILTER (
            VALUES('fact'[_factDate]),
            WEEKDAY ( 'fact'[_factDate], 1 ) <> 1
                && WEEKDAY ( 'fact'[_factDate], 1 ) <> 7
        ),
        'fact'[_factDate]
    )
```

[image: Solution]

The minimum dependency of the calculations are having a calendar table like this

| Calendar_Date | Calendar_Year | Calendar_Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2000 | 2000 | 1 |

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 0):

first create a **calculated column** in you calendar table (**Dates for my case**) with this below code-

```
Column = if(
        FORMAT(Dates[date],"dddd") = "Saturday"
            || FORMAT(Dates[date],"dddd") = "Sunday",
        0,
        1
    )
```

now create a **measure** as below-

```
weekday = sum(Dates[Column])
```

now, create visual with month and new measure.